# How can I get autoincrement Predictable ID with C# and MongoDb

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb

I'm using MongoDb with a .Net Core 3 solution and here is my problem.
I chosed MongoDb for various reasons and I want as much as possible to stick with it.
I want to be able to insert an object into the db and retrieve it with an id that I can guess programmatically.
My object would be something like:

```
public class myclass
{
    public int Id {get; set;}

    public string SomeValue {get; set;} 
}
```

But doing it that way will just insert the default value of `int` and that's it. I don't know the id beforehand that's why I want autoincrement basically.
I also tried to us the format:

```
public class myclass
{
    [BsonId]
    public ObjectId Id {get; set;}

    public string SomeValue {get; set;} 
}
```

And even though it does autoincrement, it does it the mongo way.
`ObjectId("5e68f3b3407d9b261b5312fc")` that is not very predictable in that way.
which from [Here](https://api.mongodb.com/csharp/1.6/html/dd6074e6-ef82-d1d9-7731-d59972ec3e65.htm) Contains this:
[image: objectid properties]
And that's quite handy so I tried to use `Increment` but can't manage to get it to work when I retrieve it.

```
var doc = await _collection.FindAsync(x => x.ID.Increment == myId).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

or something like this:

```
var doc = await _collection.FindAsync(new FilterDefinitionBuilder<Question>().Gt(x => x.ID.Increment, myId)).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

this way worked with the `int` ID like if I try to get the `ID == 0`

Question is is there a better or proper way to have autoincrement `int` or whatever predictable value with C# and mongoDb ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a sequential table that contains a list of names for unique ids and the current number unique ID's (probably as longs if you think you'll build up more than 2 billion records) and write a stored procedure that will securely return the next value for the supplied name and increment the current number by one in one transaction.  Then whenever you need to save something to the database get a unique id, compress it (convert to base64, 32, whatever) and use it as your row id.

The advantage of this method is that once you've written it once you can then use it for any other id tag that you want.  We use a similar table for generating different ids for clients, contacts, activities, actions, etc.

This is the code that we use to get the unique number

```
    ''' <summary>
    ''' Returns the next unique number for the supplied id in the system,
    ''' automatically refreshes when the numbers run out
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <param name="name">The name of the unique number to return</param>
    ''' <returns></returns>
    ''' <remarks></remarks>
    Public Function GetUniqueNumber(ByVal name As String) As Integer
        Dim sequentialRow As MSLDataModel.sequentialRow
        AcquireWriterLock("GetUniqueNumber")
        Try
            'Get the squential row for this name first and check that it exists
            sequentialRow = CachedData.sequential.FindByid(name)
            If sequentialRow Is Nothing Then
                CachedData.AcceptChanges()
                sequentialRow = CachedData.sequential.AddsequentialRow(name, name, 1, 1, Integer.MaxValue, 10, 1)
                databaseConnection.SaveDataTable(CachedData.sequential)
            End If

            Dim number As Integer
            Dim range As Integer
            'if we have run out of numbers then read more numbers from the database
            If sequentialRow.range < 1 Then
                Dim retry As Integer = 0
                While (Not ReadUniqueNumber(sequentialRow) And retry < 10)
                    retry = +1
                End While
            End If
            'get the current number and reduce the available numbers by 1
            number = sequentialRow.number
            range = sequentialRow.range
            sequentialRow.range = range - 1
            sequentialRow.number = number + 1
            Return number
        Finally
            ReleaseWriterLock()
        End Try
    End Function

    Private Function ReadUniqueNumber(ByVal sequentialRow As MSLDataModel.sequentialRow) As Boolean
        Try
            Dim col As Dictionary(Of String, Object)
            Dim res As DataSet
            col = New Dictionary(Of String, Object)
            col.Add("@id", sequentialRow.id)
            res = databaseConnection.RunStoredProcedure("seq_update", col)
            If res.Tables(0).Rows.Count > 0 Then
                Dim row As DataRow
                row = res.Tables(0).Rows(0)
                sequentialRow.number = row.Item("number")
                sequentialRow.range = row.Item("range")
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            MSLODBCAbstractionLayer.Logger.LogException(ex)
            Return False
        End Try
        Return True
    End Function
```

And the corresponding method in our Database Abstraction Layer

```
    Public Function GetUniqueNumber(ByVal uniqueName As String) As Integer Implements MediaSystems.InterfaceDefinitions.IMSLDataAbstractionLayer.GetUniqueNumber
        Logger.StartFunction()
        Try
            'Check to see if this action can be performed

            'get the unique number from the cache
            Return Cache.GetUniqueNumber(uniqueName)
        Finally
            Logger.EndFunction()
        End Try
    End Function
```

Comment: Isn't there a huge performance drawback with this method ? Also if you have a code example I would hugely appreciate it.

Comment: We have two stored procedures, one that returns a single number, and another that returns a number that is x higher than the current number.  In our CRM/Booking system new rows are created by user input so we only use the single number procedure, but in batch processing apps we use the multi number procedure.

Comment: I can't give you the stored procedure as it's Sybase/MS Sql specific, so you'll need to work out how to do the transaction locking yourself.